# Using Xamarin Studio to add a Lollipop Toolbar to my project

Tags: c#, android, xml, xamarin, xamarin-studio

How can I add the Android Toolbar (which replaces the ActionBar) to my Android 5.0 Lollipop app in Xamarin Studio? I have checked out the samples and I just don't get how I can add menu items/icons /buttons to the Lollipop toolbar in my app.

Comment: Why the downvote? What's the point in downvoting? It doesn't achieve anything. A comment describing what _you_ think is wrong with a post is more constructive.

Comment: I did not downvote this but my guess would be that someone expected you to include some of your own code and/or links to the samples you have already checked.

Comment: @BSMP Yeah, I dunno. I guess I suck at searching (even though I spend hours and even days searching before I ask questions). At the time of writing this question, I hadn't found anything about _Toolbars_ for android apps.

Comment: The only sample I had was the ActionBar one from an old project (that I had written in Android Studio), and didn't think it could be used with Xamarin Studio.

Comment: I didn't mean to imply that I think some are out there, just that someone else may have assumed that there were and downvoted you for not including links.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, incase anybody comes across this post looking for an answer, I have found a [sample on GitHub](https://github.com/xamarin/monodroid-samples/tree/master/android_l/Toolbar) while searching for something completely unrelated.

Comment: Also, here is the support v7 version: https://github.com/xamarin/monodroid-samples/tree/master/Supportv7/AppCompat/Toolbar  Additionally, I did a blog post on it here: http://blog.xamarin.com/android-tips-hello-toolbar-goodbye-action-bar/

Comment: Update: Please disregard this answer, as it did not help me (fully) solve the problem. I now have access to a toolbar sample, however I still do not understand how they got the menu options and icons there. I just can't find it in the Properties Pad or xml/axml files.

Comment: You can use the standard OnCreateOptionsMenu https://github.com/xamarin/monodroid-samples/blob/master/Supportv7/AppCompat/Toolbar/Supportv7Toolbar/MainActivity.cs#L48-L57 for your toolbar that is there. If you insert another toolbar (let's say on the bottom). you would just call InflateMenu: https://github.com/xamarin/monodroid-samples/blob/master/Supportv7/AppCompat/Toolbar/Supportv7Toolbar/MainActivity.cs#L31-L35